# Explanation of $\frac{sgn(x) + 1}{2} \approx sigmoid(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, proof-explanation, approximation

I saw an approximation in my textbook which states

$$ \frac{sgn(x) + 1}{2} \approx sigmoid(x)$$

Why is this true? Is there any famous reference to where this approximation came from or even some kind of derivation/proof? As I cannot find a relationship, one is continuous and one is not.

Here is a plot of sgn(x)

[image]

And here is a plot of sigmoid(x). I can see they are similar at $y=0,1$ but not in between, as there is a jump.

[image]

Comment: The left hand side, also known as the heaviside function, can be considered the limit of $\mathrm{sigmoid}(nx)$ as n grows very large. Graph it and you can see it for yourself. I don't think it's anything past that.

Comment: It is almost certainly the latter.

Comment: Sigmoid functions are functions which have certain [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) (they may differ a bit from author to author). Your function satisfies most of these properties, which are usually required.

Comment: The unit jump is a non-continuous sigmoid function, but I encounter more the other direction, using a smooth sigmoid function to approximate a unit jump, for instance to make a non-continuous differential equation continuous in a close approximation.

Answer (score 1):

For positive $x\gg1$, $e^{-x}\ll1$ so $\sigma(x)\approx1-e^{-x}\approx1$. For positive $-x\gg1$, use $\sigma(-x)=1-\sigma(x).$ Small $x$ satisfy $\sigma(x)\approx\sigma(0)=\tfrac12$, in line with the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) for a Fourier treatment of step functions.

Comment: IMHO, the Gibbs phenomenon is not the point here. In fact, one should only remark that the approximation the OP has given should be replaced by this one: $\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x) + 1}{2}=H(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}$ sigmoid$(nx)$ (at least in the sense of distributions)

Comment: @JeanMarie I only mention it because it's one motivation for the definition $\operatorname{sgn}0:=\tfrac12$.